# Unit Testing - Resolution of the dependency failed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, controller, unity-container

I'm very new to the Unit Testing. Just Wanted to unit test existing webapi controller. Inside the controller, I'm  resolving dependencies using **UnityContainer**.

While running the test case, getting an exception

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed

Can anyone guide me to resolve this dependency? Thanks in advance!!

```cs
public class PQController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int pqid)
    {
        if (!IsValidPqIds || sourceId  <= 0)
        {               
            return BadRequest();
        }       

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IPQAdapter, PQAdapterDesktop>();
        var pqDesktopAdapter = container.Resolve<IPQAdapter>();

        var pq = pqDesktopAdapter.GetPQByIds<PQDesktop>(pqid);

        return Ok(pq);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class TestPriceQuoteController
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_PriceQuoeById_Should_Return_Valid_PriceQuote()
    {
        var pqController = new PQController();            

        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = pqController.GetById(55560);
        var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<PQDesktop>;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
        Assert.AreEqual(55560, contentResult.Content.PQId);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Test project, do you have a reference to the project containing `PQAdapterDesktop` class?

Comment: Does you PQAdapterDesktop has an empty constructor?

Comment: I haven't used unity but your code looks very wrong.  Calling RegisterType and Resolve for the same type in the same function seems very odd.  You may as well just be newing up an instance.  Normally I would expect your container to have been setup previously so that you could use something like constructor injection to resolve your controller's dependencies. This also make it a lot easier to supply stubs or mocks for unit testing.